# Creating an image element with src containing certain query string parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create an HTML image element like this one:

```
<img src="www.example.com?param1=aid&param2=sid&param3=user&param4=now" />
```

I tried doing this:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var aid = 123456;
var sid = 78910;
var user = "abcd";
```

How can I create the element from this data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create an `img` *element* using `document.createElement("img")`. *(A* tag *is an HTML* text *concept; when working with the DOM, you're working with elements and nodes and such.)*

You set its `src`, a string, using the `src` reflected property of that element. To create that string you'd use string concatenation (`+`) or a template literal (see below).

So (string concatenation):

```
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.example.com?param1=" + aid +
              "&param2=" + sid +
              "&param3 = " + encodeURIComponent(user) +
              "&param4=" + now;
```

Or (template literal):

```
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = `http://www.example.com?param1=${aid}&param2=${sid}&param3=${encodeURIComponent(user)}&param4=${now}`;
```

Then you'd want to append that to the DOM somewhere ([`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), etc.).

Note the `encodeURIComponent` on the non-numeric one, `user`. Both the names and values in a query string *must* be URI-encoded. But I haven't bothered on `param1`, `param2`, etc. because they only have characters that don't need URI-encoding (same for numbers in normal form). But when in any doubt, encode, it won't do any harm even when unnecessary.

Re your comment:

> And presumably if I'd like to add attributes to the img element it'd be like img.height=1 and img.width=1?

The specification [lists the properties of `img` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) (see the "DOM Interface"). Yes, both `height` and `width` are there and [setting them has the same effect](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-img-height) as using the `height` and `width` attributes, although you might want to use a stylesheet instead.

Not all attributes have reflected properties. For those that don't, you'd use `setAttribute("name", value)` (the value will be converted to a string if it isn't already one).

Comment: Good to know about the template string too. And that's just going to be JS no libraries or anything? Fantastic.

Comment: @DougFirr: Yup, once everyone upgrades their browsers, so ~2021 or so. :-) Meanwhile, transpilers like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) already support it. [Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=let%20a%20%3D%20%22ay%22%2C%20b%20%3D%20%22bee%22%3B%0Alet%20s%20%3D%20%60a%20%3D%20%24%7Ba%7D%2C%20b%20%3D%20%24%7Bb%7D%2C%20b%20upper%20%3D%20%24%7Bb.toUpperCase()%7D%60%3B%0Aconsole.log(s)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Strings in JS can be chained together with the `+` operator. Number values will be coerced to strings (although that sometimes won't work as expected).